# C++ ^ What is it for?

Tags: .net, c++-cli

I'm reading a program in (.NET) C++ made by someone else, and I can't figure out what this means:

```
BinaryWriter^ file = gcnew BinaryWriter( File::Open( "Data.al", FileMode::OpenOrCreate ));
```

What DOES the ^ do in this sentence?

and what about this:

```
void GetEEDataRx(array<Byte> ^%EE)
```

What is the purpose of the ^%

Comment: Its a managed pointer in this context

Comment: "^ XOR Bitwise exclusive OR" http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/operators/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is [C++/CLI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI).

The `^` is declaring a managed pointer (as opposed to a raw pointer using `*`).  The `BinaryWriter` object is being allocated with `gcnew` instead of `new`, so it will be garbage-collected when it is not being used anymore.

The `^%` is a tracking reference. It is the equivalent of the C# `ref` keyword.

You can read the documentation to learn more about C++/CLI, now that you know what it is.

Comment: and what about the %?

Comment: okok, good :). I'll accept the anwser in 7 mins